# Java overflow have different result when calculating on a calculator to the IDE result?

Tags: java

I don't understand where I am going wrong with the calculation I did, why did I receive a different result to the IDE console. Console receives a result of `14464` for the `println` for my `ShortTotal`. But via manual calculation on a calculator I received a similar number but `+1` which was `14465`?

I understand what the short type maximum and minimum values are. Here is what I have done so far:

As the short maximum value is around `32,767`. So it goes to the minimum again with the remaining amount. So on a calculator, you can check this by doing: 
`1000 x (bytevalue+shortvalue + intvalue) = 80000`. As `80,000` is bigger than short max val it overflows with the remainder. `80,000-32767 =47233` then add this value back onto minimum which is :  `- 32768 + 47233 = 14465`

I managed to get close to the value of `14464` but don't know why I'm receiving `14465`?

```
package com.company;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
   byte ByteValue = 10;
   short ShortValue = 20;
   int IntValue = 50;
   long LongTotal = 50000 + 10 * (ByteValue + ShortValue + IntValue);
        System.out.println(LongTotal);
//The issue in question is below.
        short ShortTotal = (short) (1000 * (ByteValue + ShortValue + IntValue));
      System.out.println(ShortTotal);
    }
}
```

Comment: In your manual calculation you are treating 32767 and -32768 as the same number, but they are different by 1. The code is correct, your manual math isn't.

Comment: Unrelated: please follow java naming conventions. Variable names go camelCase, only classes go UpperCamelCase.

Comment: `(short) 32767+1 = (short) -32768`  You forgot the +1

Comment: Just a small comment: please use proper variable names, that is the way how others and the community can understand your code better. For example, 'TotalLong' should be 'total'. For more details, please read this: https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand your confusion.

80,000 as an `int` value gives the following bit pattern:

```
00000000000000010011100010000000
```

Chopping off the first two bytes gives you the following bit pattern for the `short` value:

```
0011100010000000
```

Converted to decimal, this is:

```
14464
```

Or to put it differently: a short can represent 2^16 possible values:

```
80000 - (2^16) = 80000 - 65536 = 14464
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, I wasn't clear with my response so that I apologise for. Where the confusion was not within the code but more my manual calculation that I did after to confirm the result of 14464. But via manual calculation I received 14465. A user call f1sh had commented stating that I treated both 32767 and -32768 as the same number which is probably the issue which I'm trying to get my head round.

Comment: You're correct in your min and max values, but are leaving the zero out of account as a possible value that needs to be accounted for.